# How to pass lat and long in open layer 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have two JavaScript variables values comes from two text fields `t1` and `t2`. When I pass values like:

```
var point=new ol.geometry.point(new ol.proj.transform([-81.9571,35.01],'4326','3857'));
```

Something like above works but not if I pass the variables. It points to wrong location. Like below code:

```
var point=new ol.geometry.point(new ol.proj.transform([t1,t2],'4326','3857'));
```

Comment: you might have to cast the values to `int`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your coordinate value is not a string type:

```
var lon = parseFloat(t1);
var lat = parseFloat(t2);
```

Use a valid projection identifier:

```
var coord = ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

All together:

```
var coord = ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(t1), parseFloat(t2)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var point = new ol.geom.Point(coord);
```